# Laravel No query results for model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello so I've been using Laravel 5 for like 3 days already and I'm having a problem. I am testing my edit page and I am getting the error `No query results for model`. This is the sample link `http://localhost:8000/profile/sorxrob/edit`. The `sorxrob` there is a username. This is my route:

```
Route::bind('user', function($user) {
    return App\User::where('username', $user)->first();
});

Route::get('profile/{user}', 'ConsultaProfileController@viewProfile');

Route::get('profile/{user}/edit', 'ConsultaProfileController@edit');
```

And in my `ConsultaProfileController` here is the public function:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $account = User::findOrFail($id);
    return view('consulta.edit', compact('account'));
}
```

Whenever I TRY `http://localhost:8000/profile/sorxrob/edit` it gives me the error `No query results for model` but when I change the route to `Route::get('profile/{id}/edit', 'ConsultaProfileController@edit');` it works but the url should be now `http://localhost:8000/profile/6/edit` where 6 is the id of sorxob. I want the username to be used, but I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you already have a `User` object.

You have binded `user` to a `User` object. So the parameter you are receiving is a `User` object, not an `id`. So no need to query again.

Just use

```
public function edit($user)
{
    return view('consulta.edit', compact('user'));
}
```